# ConTeXt: Line Break for chinese characters

Tags: context, chinese

I automatically generate documents in which users can input any kind of text.

If the user enters chinese characters the text overflows and no line break is occuring.

How can I prohibit the text from overflowing?

(my goal is to generate robust documents in which every character entered is always displayed in the final documents without extra configuration needed)

```
\definefallbackfamily[mainface][serif][notoserifcjksc][range={cjkunifiedideographs,cjkcompatibility,cjkunifiedideographsextensiona,yijinghexagramsymbols,cjksymbolsandpunctuation}]
\definefallbackfamily[mainface][sans][notosanscjksc][range={cjkunifiedideographs,cjkcompatibility,cjkunifiedideographsextensiona,yijinghexagramsymbols,cjksymbolsandpunctuation}]

\definefallbackfamily[mainface][serif][NotoSerif][range=0x00000-0xFFFFF]
\definefallbackfamily[mainface][sans][NotoSans][range=0x00000-0xFFFFF]

\definefontfamily[mainface][serif][TeX Gyre Pagella]
\definefontfamily[mainface][sans][NotoSans]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext

統高比歴写横深原故上現質著毒太念植出使。紙約音予草足資倉報人己読。出黒挑崎成都中場中億芸読。警更追陸手表詰女区力像統稿序。出和開告情恐色番場無料実後調威聞思掲報本。行味半対民未挙大特口佐物久建真容。体姿出全禁委着与帳南氏望真売。告路経就停収通続分政手対康況再官体聞未。制愉北寿載少策聞爆使特埋益。

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable line breaking for chinese (as well as korean and japanese) text with the `\setscript` command.

When you have also footnotes in your document which contain chinese text you have to replace the `\setscript` command with `\setglobalscript` but it is advised to use the global setting only for documents which chinese only to chinese as the main language.

```
\setuppapersize [A5]

\definefallbackfamily
  [mainface]
  [serif]
  [notoserifcjksc]
  [range={cjkunifiedideographs,cjkcompatibility,cjkunifiedideographsextensiona,yijinghexagramsymbols,cjksymbolsandpunctuation}]

\definefontfamily [mainface] [serif] [TeX Gyre Pagella]

\setupbodyfont [mainface]

\setscript [hanzi]

\starttext

統高比歴写横深原故上現質著毒太念植出使。
紙約音予草足資倉報人己読。
出黒挑崎成都中場中億芸読。
警更追陸手表詰女区力像統稿序。
出和開告情恐色番場無料実後調威聞思掲報本。
行味半対民未挙大特口佐物久建真容。
体姿出全禁委着与帳南氏望真売。
告路経就停収通続分政手対康況再官体聞未。
制愉北寿載少策聞爆使特埋益。

\stoptext
```

[image]